# Is it possible to run an application from a remote server on a website?

Tags: web-services, web

I have a website that I would like the customers to navigate to a page where it runs a program that I wrote.  However, the program is on a separate server.  How might I run the application from that remote server onto the server that hosts the website?

It looks like ideally I'll have my web host as GoDaddy.com and I'd like to run my application from that website.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If your other application is a web application, then just use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of technology are you employing to deploy the apps? ASP? PHP?

It seems that you were actually trying to "Window" the app on another server to your current site, if that's the case you can just simply link the app inside an iframe of your site.
Reference -http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I will be employing ASP most likely.  But yes, "windowing" the app is the best description that you could give.